# Find expectation of Z (normal)

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expectation

Assume the following [PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function).

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2π}}e^{-(z^2 / 2)}$$

Find E(z).

For now, I got

E(z) = $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_z(z) dz $

And for any odd function F, (i.e. F(−x) = −F(x)∀x ∈ R),

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_z(z) dz= 0$

So, the function zf(z) = $$ z*e^{-(z^2 / 2)} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2π}}$$

is an odd function. Hence E(Z) = 0.

Is it correct? Or is there another way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your theorem about integral of an odd function being equal to $0$ is valid only if the integral exists, so you would need to show first that $E|Z| <\infty$, before applying theorem (you may obtain wrongly $EX=0$ for Cauchy distribution because of omitting this assumption). If you don't know that Expected Value of this distribution is finite then you may calculate the Expected Value directly:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}z \cdot e^\frac{-z^2}{2}dz=\int_{-\infty}^{-\infty} \frac{z}{-z \cdot \sqrt{2 \pi}} e^u du=\int_{-\infty}^{-\infty} \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^u du=0-0=0$$

We substituded $u=-\frac{z^2}{2}, du=-z dz$, so $dz=\frac{-1}{z}du$. Also $\lim_{z \to -\infty} u=-\infty$ and $\lim_{z \to \infty} u=-\infty$.

Comment: You had the same limits in last integral so no need to compute.

Comment: I did it just to show that it's not a indeterminate form $\infty - \infty$. It is necessary as I could wrongly show that (for example again) Cauchy distribution has Expected Value equal to $0$.

Comment: @M.Stawiski thank you~. so every time when i encounter this kind of problems just try directly?

Comment: No, sometimes it's easier directly but usually it's easier to show that the integral exists and then use the theorem above. For example if you knew that variance of normal distribution exists (because you'd proven that before) you could just use the theorem without calculations.

Comment: If you knew that these parameters are $EZ$ and $Var \ Z$ then yes but firstly that needs to be proven and secondly if you knew that then you wouldn't need to show that $EZ=0$ because you would already know that.

Comment: @M.Stawiski oh i see. thanks.

Comment: Case closed. Maybe it's the lazy physcist (though this is definitely not a general statement about physicists) that I am!!